# "data" field is not working in Ethereum QR Code mobile payment

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, qrcode

Recently, I am working on generating an Ethereum QR code that mobile wallet (e.g. imToken) can scan and pay from there.
But the problem is that I cannot pass the **data** value.

I use C# code to generate the QR code as following:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                QRCodeGenerator qrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator();
                var url = "ethereum:" + coinAddress + "?amount=" + value + "&data=3130302c4852313739383337363236342c3836";
                ViewBag.QRCodeUrl = url;
                QRCodeData qrCodeData = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode(url, QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
                QRCode qrCode = new QRCode(qrCodeData);
                using (Bitmap bitMap = qrCode.GetGraphic(20))
                {
                    bitMap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
                    ViewBag.QRCodeImage = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
                }
            }
```

I follow this url syntax:

```
ethereum:<address>[?amount=<ethamount>][&data=<Hexadecimal>]
```

I can get the **address** and **amount**
But not the **data**

Please help correcting me if I have done wrongly. 
Any solutions or corrections, I highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You ever get this solved?